# Docker dashboard not showing file sharing option

Tags: docker

I am new to docker, and am running Docker for Windows 10. I am not seeing drives for sharing?

I tried restarting, resetting, etc, but it didn't work

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey Sorry but `drives for sharing` is the linux only version of Docker.

Please see this thread for more details:

https://forums.docker.com/t/shared-drives-option-not-showing-up-in-docker-for-windows-settings/35725